# cocos2d glview vs scene, what's is the relation between glview and scene?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2d, and I am trying to find out how glview interact with scene?
update new question:

for example,  the glview in the AppDelegate.m, I can see that. But for IntroLayer and HelloWorldLayer, there are not. is that glview in delegate the only one to draw everything on screen? if I add a UIButton to  this glview, will it show up in every scene?

I have seen a lots of code using  "add subview" to add a glview to shareDiector(cocos2d 2.0), then push scene. 
then I am very Curious, which will be on the front? scene or glview ? Or glview is used to hold scene?

what if I add a gusture to glview's subview, will layers (in the scene）swalow the touch event?

Can anyone help me on this? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The glView is the OpenGL view where OpenGL content is rendered on the screen. It is derived from UIView.

CCScene is an abstract concept of cocos2d. It is derived from CCNode which is derived from NSObject. CCScene is by definition, not by necessity, the root node of a cocos2d Scene. It allows adding more nodes like sprites and labels to it.

Cocos2D uses this scene hierarchy to determine the order by which to issue OpenGL draw commands to the glView. Think of it as layers in your image program (Photoshop or similar), whereas the glView represents the entire picture being drawn with all layers rendered on top of each other.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think I understand this scenario you mentioned. glview  use to draw everything on the screen. As I find in AppDelegate.m , "[director_ setView:glView];" ccdirector is a singleton class, only one director exist, is this the only one glview in whole application? if it is, then if I add a UIButton to this glview, shouldn't I see it in all scene?

Comment: is there a life cycle of cocos2d appliation for cocos2d 2.0 or your Kobold2d? your Kobold2d api document is great, very useful. At the beginning, I was trying to use Kobold2d, but failed later. I get confused when using template with uikit. As I don't understand the hierarchy, and the steps cocos2d application how starts . Could you add this on your kobold2d website?(just a suggestion, :) )